# A curve of constant curvature and zero torsion must be a circle

Tags: multivariable-calculus, differential-geometry, 3d, curves, curvature

From Elementary Differential Geometry by Pressley

**I don't understand the last paragraph.** Why does it show $\gamma$ lies on the sphere $\mathcal S$ with center $\mathbf a$ and radius $1/\kappa$?

[image]

Answer (score 3):

$$ \|\gamma - \mathbf{a}\| = {1\over\kappa}$$ says that the distance from $\gamma$ to $\mathbf{a}$ is the constant value $1\over \kappa$.

Now, what is the definition of a sphere $S$ of radius $1\over\kappa$ about $\mathbf a$?