# Curves in $\mathbb{R} ^3 $

Tags: multivariable-calculus, curves

Let $\gamma :I \subset \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R} ^ 3 $an arc length parameterization of a smooth curve C.

If  $\tau (s)= 0$   for all  $s \in I $,  C is contained in a plane?

And if also, the curvature is constant and none zero for all $s \in I $. Is C  (or is contained in) a circle?

I don´t know how to prove it, Do I have to use the Frenet-Serret equations?

Comment: What is $\tau$?

Comment: @5xum Is the unit tangent vector of $\gamma$, and $\tau = \frac{\gamma'}{  \| \gamma'' \|}$

Comment: @jessica No, $\tau$ is the torsion.

Comment: Duplicate of [A space curve is planar if and only if its torsion is everywhere 0](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/939275/a-space-curve-is-planar-if-and-only-if-its-torsion-is-everywhere-0) and https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1505638/620957